# Get bootstrap radio value from href buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a problem when trying to get values of radio with jQuery.

Here are my radio buttons:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div id="radioBtn" class="btn-group">
        <a class="btn btn-warning radio-selector btn-sm active" data-toggle="happy" data-title="pub">Pub</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning radio-selector btn-sm notActive" data-toggle="happy" data-title="pri">Pri</a>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="happy" id="happy">
</div>
<a id="add" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Add</a>
```

And here the JavaScript code to get the selected value:

```
$('#add').live("click",function() {
    var getdata = $('#radioBtn .radio-selector:checked').data("title");
    alert(getdata);
}
```

But all time I get `undefined` value! Any solution to get the `data-title` in the radio buttons?

Comment: What is your jQuery version?

Comment: Latest version, problem already solved, thank's.

Comment: My version are: jquery 1.11.0, not latest sorry just verified.

Comment: @MacBen [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in 1.9! Which is why I said =)

Comment: Yes you are right :) good remark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('#add').live("click",function() 
{
    var getdata = $('#radioBtn > a.active').data("title");
    alert(getdata);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, the problem even solved with `#radioBtn .active`.